# Is my pet worth anything?

Tags: stardew-valley

Simply as the title says: I have a dog and the only thing he ever was noticeable for me was, when blocking passages I wanted to pass.

So is it anything usefull for except showing me a heart over his head when clicked?

If not so: How to get rid of it?

Comment: You monster....

Comment: @SaintWacko. "*Your faithful Companion Dog will have to be euthanized.*" - GlaDOS

Comment: From what I can tell, your pet serves no purpose at all. You can show your affection by interacting with it daily but it appears that you cannot remove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pets currently have no purpose (except making you go *d'awwwww* when you get it). It's been request by the fanbase that they be given a purpose in a later update, and the developer is considering adding new ways to interact with them (though note that "interaction" doesn't necessarily mean "purpose").

Rather than a purpose though, it does have one minor *effect*:

> Its happiness is part of [Grandpa's scoring calculation](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Grandpa).

Apart from those, currently the pet has mostly vanishingly subtle, subjective, or aesthetic purposes:

- It gives a new farm a sense of activity and life, [which was the original purpose](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/4b8s7v/im_concernedape_developer_of_stardew_valley_ask/d170mz1):

  > My original purpose for the pets was to add some "life" to the farm in the early days before you have chickens, etc. They are supposed to just be cute aesthetic creatures that don't require any work. But I will try and think of ways to make them more interesting without straying too far from the original purpose.
- It gives you an early lesson in how the game's animals work, before you have ones you need to take care of (i.e., that they block your way, they can be pushed if there's room, they're sort of random and not very fast, short ones are easily visually lost in grass, they won't damage your crops, they can be interacted with, etc.)
- Players who have a penchant for roleplaying get obvious benefits from its presence
- The choice of pet expresses the player in screenshots

There's currently no way to get rid of your pet, and I get the sense that the developer has no intention of making it possible.

Answer (score -3):

well my friend I am sorry to say your pets serve no purpose except they are cute and fill up a space that was empty. You can get your pet to love you though by interacting with it and petting it a notification will pop up saying " your pet's name loves you" and it makes you happy for a second and then your back to your normal routine on your farm. It is sad but honestly you must except the fact that even in real life the only purpose for pets is companionship to fill up a whole that will never be filled by humans who actually have a point in our world. So in a way I can see why they don't do anything besides move around or scurry or pounce because in real life they probably do less. How many times have you seen your cat stay up till night or a dog do the same. They are a thing we pet that is why they are called pets that is all they do for you let them pet you except of course if they don't even let you do that! Anyhow this sorta makes sense and I understand the point to the fact they don't do anything.